# Screen Mirror with remote display app for samsung TV

Tags: android, samsung-smart-tv

I want to develop an app on android that uses screen mirroring with Samsung TV. I'm looking to use my android app screen as a remote(say a game controller) & TV screen to run the actual game. My initial approach was learning google cast but it needs a chromecast dongle which I don't want to use for this project. I want to use Samsung Smart TV's Screen Mirroring feature to do so. After some googling, I figured out that samsung uses Allshare Framework API for screen mirroring/cast but I'm not completely sure on this. I'm currently struggling to find a proper documentation for screen mirroring. If someone can point to the correct documentation link then that'd be awesome. Also, please correct me if I'm wrong with the assumption that this can be achieved using Allshare API only.

Answer (score 1):

It seems Samsung have came out with this new SDK - Samsung Multiscreen SDK( or maybe I've found it now :)). This [link](http://multiscreen.samsung.com/index.html) should cover most of the questions I've asked above. Also, if you are Unity user, Samsung has their own version of Unity which comes intalled with Samsung Multiscreen Game SDK. But you need to send a partnership request to samsung in order to use this version of Unity. Apart from these two, you can also use Connect SDK which is independent of any technology, i.e. it covers almost every other technology used for Cast. For exmple, if you have a Samsung Smart TV at your home & a Roku connection. With Samsung SDK you can only discover Smart TV but not Roku stick. Whereas, with Connect SDK you can discover Samsung Tv as well as Roku & any other Cast device which is available in your network.